# React toggle class on just one component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating, in `componentDidMount`, a lots of `<div>`'s.

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        componentLoaded: false,
        divs: []
    }
}

componentDidMount () {
    this.createDivs()
}

createDivs () {
    // Actually, this divs are created dinamically and with infinite scroll
    let divs = <div className='container'>
        <div className='item' onClick={() => { /* Add class */ }}>...</div>
        <div className='item' onClick={() => { /* Add class */ }}>...</div>
        <div className='item' onClick={() => { /* Add class */ }}>...</div>
        /* ... n divs ... */
    </div>
    let newDivs = this.state.divs
    newDivs.push(divs)
    this.setState({
        componentLoaded: true,
        divs: newDivs
    })
}

render () {
    return {this.state.componentLoaded ? this.state.divs : null }
    /* In my return, if X event occurs, re-call this.createDivs() to add more divs */
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve, is to toggle a class into only one of the `.item` divs, and then if clicking another one, remove it from the before and add it to the one was clicked.

I've tried to add an attribute to the state, but it didn't add it. I also searched for some solutions, but I always find solutions which doesn't toggle, as they are "toggled individually" in separated components.

Hoping to find some help, maybe this thing is real simple, but for now, I cannot figure out how to make it.

PS: I'm adding the `createDivs` into the state because it's an infinite scroll that re-uses the function, so I just push them into the state and the scroll won't go to the top again when adding the previous ones + the new ones.

Comment: Why is `this.state.divs` an array when you only ever have one div in it (the container)? Is there code you haven't shown that will add more?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, i had to mention, that there can also be many container's. But thanks all to all the help you provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In problems like these it is always helpful to **determine what goes into react's state**. You want the state to be as lightweight as possible (so you store only the stuff which is necessary)

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedDiv: null,
  };

  handleClick = id => {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      // sets it to null if its already active else, sets it active
      selectedDiv: prev.selectedDiv === id ? null : id,
    }));
  };
  render() {
    // Array to map over
    const divs = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    const { selectedDiv } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {divs.map(div => {
          return (
            <div
              key={div}
              className={selectedDiv === div ? "item class_to_add" : "item"}
              onClick={() => this.handleClick(div)}
            >Item {div}</div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the above examples we are **only storing the unique Id** of the div in the state and using that to determine if the selected div is active or not, if it is then we simply remove it from the state. The above solution does not require any complex lifecycle methods, my advice would be to keep the component as simple as possible.

PS. not part of the answer but I suggest you to look into the newer hooks API its more intuitive and most probably the future of react

Comment: Thanks for this. This will probably work. I cannot use hooks as I think we are using older versions of react. Tomorrow I'll test it and give the solution as the correct one if goes well =)

Comment: The reason for why I'm putting the divs inside the state, is because I'm adding an infinite scroll to a div, so I just have to re-use my `createDivs` function and push it into the `divs` from state

Comment: Well thats not a good way of achieving infinite scroll and storing DOM elements in state is almost never required, not to mention the performance issues it will cost since the entire container needs to reload on every single scroll!, I suggest using a more specialized library for this use case https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/

Answer (score 0):

First, note that you're breaking a React rule here:

```
this.state.divs.push(divs)
```

You must never directly modify state. The correct thing there is either:

```
this.setState({divs}); // Replaces any previous ones
```

or

```
this.setState(({divs: oldDivs}) => {divs: [...oldDivs, divs]}); // Adds to any previous ones
```

**However**, the "React way" to do this would probably be not to store those divs in state at all; instead, store the information related to them in state, and render them (in `render`) as needed, with the appropriate classes. The information about which one of them has the class would typically either be information on the items themselves, or some identifying information about the item (such as an `id` of some kind) held in your component's state.

Here's an example using items that have an `id`:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // No items yet
            items: null,
            // No selected item yet
            selectedId: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.createDivs();
    }

    createDivs() {
        // Simulate ajax or whatever
        setTimeout(() => {
            const items = [
                {id: 42,  label: "First item"},
                {id: 12,  label: "Second item"},
                {id: 475, label: "third item"},
            ];
            this.setState({items});
        }, 800);
    }

    render () {
        const {items, selectedId} = this.state;
        if (!items) {
            // Not loaded yet
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                {items.map(({id, label}) => (
                    <div
                        key={id}
                        className={`item ${id === selectedId ? "selected" : ""}`}
                        onClick={() => this.setState({selectedId: id})}
                    >
                    {label}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.selected {
    color: green;
}
.item {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There are a few things which make this answer incomplete

1. The className will not toggle if the user clicks twice on the same element
2. The methods are normal functions which needs biniding in the contructor.
3. The list elements are missing the 'key' attribute which is recommended by react

Comment: @malikbagwala - Thanks for that! 1. It's not clear to me that the OP wants that to happen. They did use the word "toggle" in their question, but only when describing moving the class to a different element. 2. There is no binding required above, I'm using an arrow function for the event handler. 3. Good point! I've added the missing `key` attribute. :-)